# Connect Php with sqlserver with out install a PDO

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to know if there is any way to `conect php with sqlserver without install a PDO` on php,
The reason that I want to avoid install a pdo is that I have a production enviroment for application and there are like 100 application already runnig, so request install this, it will be reject it.

If you have any advice It will be usefull to me.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use mssql functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are referring connecting to Microsoft SQL Server. If that is the case
you have install the php mssql_extension and use the native functions of the extension.

[mssql php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)

*** You are concerned about installing an extension to PHP. But in any case you have to do it, because the php core doesn't handle db connections. Is through the extension that you have these capabilities. So, PDO or mssql extension, has to be installed.

You are not going to break nothing just by installing a new extension to php.
You can just install the extension and tell apache(in case you are using it) to reload rather than restart. These will not affect your running application.

Answer (score 0):

> and there are like 100 application already runnig

you're not increasing the number of running applications by adding PDO support for MSSQLserver. OTOH most methods of getting a connection via an application proxy will increase the number of process running.

The only other option which makes any sense is to use [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) or the mssql extension - but if that's not already installed, then it may at least as painful as a native PDO install.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting environment is in windows you can use the following from microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098